# javascript : trouble passing value to alert from hidden tag or text

Tags: javascript

I have an html file which passes values into a java servlet to insert into the database.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function masinsert(id)
{
 var currentTime=new Date();


 var button = document.getElementById("m"+id);
 button.onclick="";
 button.value="Inserting";

 var partnumber     = document.getElementById("partnumber"+id).value;
 var itemcost       = document.getElementById("itemcost"+id).value;
 var itemlistprice  = document.getElementById("itemlistprice"+id).value;
 var sUnitMeasKey   = document.getElementById("UnitMeasKey"+id);
 var sPurchProdLine     = document.getElementById("PurchProdLine"+id);
 var sItemClassKey  = document.getElementById("itemclasskey"+id);

 var UMKselected = getSelected(sUnitMeasKey);
 var PPLselected = getSelected(sPurchProdLine);
 var ICKselected = getSelected(sItemClassKey);

 function handleHttpResponse()
  {
   if (http.readyState == 4) {
    button.value="Imported";
   }
  }


 var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object
 var tempUrl = "\MASInsert2";
 tempUrl +=  "?partnumber="+partnumber+"&"+"itemcost="+itemcost+"&"+"itemlistprice="+itemlistprice+"&"+"UnitMeasure="+UMKselected+"&"+"PurchProdLine="+PPLselected+"&"+"itemclasskey="+ICKselected;
  alert(tempUrl);
 http.open("POST", tempUrl, true);
 http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
 http.send(null);   
}


function getSelected(ele)
{
    return ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].value;
}

function getHTTPObject(){
 var xmlhttp;
 /*@cc_on
 @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
   try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e){
    try {
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
      }
  }
  @else
  xmlhttp = false;
  @end @*/
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  return xmlhttp;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name=bob method=get>
<input type=hidden id="partnumber321" name="partnumber321" value="884910U">
<input type=hidden id="itemcost321" name="itemcost321" value="1027.39">
<input type=hidden id="itemlistprice321" name="itemlistprice321" value="1129.0">
<input type=hidden id="itemdescription321" name="itemdescription321" value="XSERIES 306M SS P4 3.0GHZ 1MB">
<select id="UnitMeasKey321" name="UnitMeasKey321"><option value="112">Each</select>
<select id="PurchProdLine321" name="PurchProdLine321"><option value="18">IBM</select>
<select id="itemclasskey321" name="itemclasskey321"><option value="48">Hardware</select>
<input id="m321" type="button" onclick="masinsert('321')" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the button, the alert(partnumber) returns null (firefox) or object (IE). Am I passing these values incorrectly for the servlet to process? Any ideas why?  shouldn't it return a value?

thanks in advance

Comment: I know I shouldn't but I would suggest using jQuery for you javascript needs though Bemrose is correct in answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is returning null because there is no ID by that name.  Call `GetElementByName` if you don't want to assign ids to your inputs.

IE is returning an object because DOM elements are objects.  You need to check one of its attributes (`value` most likely) to see what it's actually set to.

IE shouldn't return an object, but it naively assumes that `GetElementById` is the same as `GetElementByName`.

Answer (score 1):

Classic IE bug **[ID vs. Name](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html)**. You will either need to specify and use id attributes, or use getElementsByName (beware it will return a "set" of matches) or the form.elements[nameOrIndex] format.

e.g.

```
alert(document.forms[myFormNameOrIndex].elements[myElementNameOrIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three things that are odd (and probably the issues):

1. How are you setting the id "partnumber"? IE giving you an object seems like you've only set the name attribute of the input box, not the id attribute.
2. You have to get the value of those properties to construct a url: `partnumber.value`
3. You are using a `GET` method for what seems like an insert. This should be a `POST`.

Comment: thanks made the corrections..  i thought POST doesn't work with servlets?  I'll go ahead and try it.